# Python Blackjack: If statement not working

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, blackjack

Hey I'm working on adding betting to my blackjack game in Python and for some reason my code now won't get passed first if statement. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code is Below:

```
def play(): 
       """ Function that involves all gameplay and allows the user to play blackjack. All 
   other functions are to support the gameplay while this function covers the actual 
   gameplay. """

   #initializing a counter for how many times the user has played
   global total_play_count

   #total winnings of a player if they already played from last hand
   global total_winnings 

   if total_play_count == 0:
        play_count = 0
   else: 
        play_count = total_play_count

    #setting a variable to hold the users total cash
    if play_count == 0: 
        winnings = 100
    else: 
        winnings = total_winnings

    #dealing user and dealer their cards
    global user_show_cards 
    global dealer_show_cards

    user_show_cards = [card(), card()]
    dealer_show_cards = [card(), card()]

    #declaring total variables
    global user_total 
    global dealer_total

    user_total = 0  
    dealer_total = 0

    #lists to hold numerical values of the hand
    global user_total_cards 
    global dealer_total_cards

    user_total_cards = [] 
    dealer_total_cards = []

    #initializing the values of cards and storing them in the lists above
    user_total_cards = ready_for_total(user_show_cards, user_total_cards, user_total)
    dealer_total_cards = ready_for_total(dealer_show_cards, dealer_total_cards, dealer_total) 

    #getting initial player totals
    user_total = sum(user_total_cards)
    dealer_total = sum(dealer_total_cards)

    #printing what is initially shown on screen
    print "" 
    print "Let's play Blackjack" 
    print "Note: Dealer stays on ALL 17s"
    print "" 
    if play_count == 0: 
        print "You start with $100"
    else: 
        pass
    bet = int(raw_input("Enter your bet: "))
    winnings -= bet
    print ""
    print "You now have $%s" %(winnings)
    print ""
    print "Your cards are %s %s" %(str(user_show_cards[0]), str(user_show_cards[1]))
    print "The dealer's up card is a(n) %s" %(str(dealer_show_cards[0]))
```

> Code won't pass the above line

```
        #first condition to see if the player has Blackjack 
    if user_total == 21: 
        print "Blackjack! You Win!"
        bet1 = bet * 2
        print "You receive $%s" %(bet1) 
        winnings += bet + bet1
        print "Your winnings now total $%s" %(str(winnings))

    elif dealer_total == 21: 
        print "Dealer got Blackjack. You lose."
        print "" 
        print "You now have $%s" %(winnings)
    else: 
        total_winnings = winnings 
        return total_winnings
        hit_or_stay()  


    print ""
    play_again = raw_input("Play again? (y/n): ") 

    if play_again == "y": 
        total_winnings = winnings 
        play_count += 1
        total_play_count = play_count
        play() 
        return total_play_count 
        return total_winnings
    else: 
        print "" 
        print "Your winnings totaled $%s" %(winnings)
        print "Goodbye, come back soon!"

play()
```

Comment: Please get rid of those `global`s.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of the code under that if statement is indented, which I don't think is what you want. Also I think that if statement doesn't do anything for you.

```
if total_play_count == 0:
        play_count = 0
   else: 
        play_count = total_play_count
```

Should just be

```
play_count = total_play_count
```

Also don't use global variables. Please just don't.